# How to make connection alive using NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection to connect to the server and Can able to send request to server and i am  getting response in delegate methods.

```
-(void) sendRequest() {
    NSString *jsonPostBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"width\":640,\"height\":480,\"ip\":\"SOME-IP\"}"];

    NSData *postData = [jsonPostBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://SOME_IP:PORT/PATH"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSString* postDataLengthString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:postDataLengthString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    if (theConnection) {
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [theConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [theConnection start];
    } else {

        // Inform the user that the connection failed.

        UIAlertView *connectFailMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NSURLConnection " message:@"Failed in viewDidLoad"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [connectFailMessage show];

    }

    NSUserDefaults *dd = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [dd setObject:@"ravi" forKey:@"name"];
}
}
```

In delegate method i am able to receive data.

Question -
After some time like in a one minute server showing **connection channel was closed** , i am not closing connection any where and i monitored my network using wireshark it showing http **FIN** to **set**.

[image]

[image]

How can i make my connection alive by using nsurlconnection??

Thanks

Comment: the connection always run with **keep-alive** mode if you want to change this into **Close** or **nokeepalive**  then change the connection mode

Comment: in here what is the purpose to want to change this

Comment: THank you @Anbu.Karthik, In my case connection was not alive i dont know why ? I want to make my connection until i close but i have not closed my connectin

Comment: @iosLearner That's not how HTTP works. What you want is a socket that you can keep open until whenever.

Comment: @JustSid : Ok, Can you give a small hint to use Socket in ios?

Comment: @iosLearner It really depends on what you want to achieve here, which is not really clear to me. A good starting point however is to google "socket iOS tutorial" or something to that effect

Comment: @iosLearner : I too have same issue, if you got answer pls post..